# Android Fabric Crashlytics crashing with Resources$NotFoundException on app launch

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourcePackageName
```

After upgrading Crashlytics from **2.6.6 to 2.9.1** we have started to notice a crash in Google Play Console.

This crash happens before Crashlytics is initialized so it is never reported in Crashlytics:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6423)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6012)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:5951)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1710)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourcePackageName (ResourcesImpl.java:248)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getResourcePackageName (Resources.java:2785)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.CommonUtils.getResourcePackageName (CommonUtils.java:767)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.CommonUtils.getResourcesIdentifier (CommonUtils.java:517)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.CommonUtils.getBooleanResourceValue (CommonUtils.java:498)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.FirebaseInfo.isFirebaseCrashlyticsEnabled (FirebaseInfo.java:52)
  at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.shouldInitializeFabric (CrashlyticsInitProvider.java:73)
  at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.onCreate (CrashlyticsInitProvider.java:25)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1759)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1734)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6420)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6012)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:5951)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1710)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

The crash doesn't impact too many users, but they can't start the app. 
I.e. we have this ratio:

- Impacted users: 93
- Reports total: 4,221

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. This is very strange - did you also update to the latest Gradle plugin - 1.25.1? Do you have Firebase in your app?

Comment: Hi @MikeBonnell , we also have this Exception. Gradle Plugin 1.25.4 and Crashlytics 2.9.4. Impacted user: 1 Reports: 110 The user uses this device: Samsung Galaxy J5(2016) (j5xnlte), Android 7.1

Comment: If it's one user, then overall I wouldn't be concerned. It's likely that have rooted their phone and caused other issues.

Comment: Issue is on API level 8 and above

Comment: Are you guys using AppBundle for APK distribution on PlayStore?

Comment: @OmNarainShukla I started getting this crash just after enabling app singing on Google server and distributing with app bundles.

Comment: We also get this issue in 3 Huawei mobiles with Android 8 and above. It is also after we begin to use app bundles. Is there any solution?

Comment: I've also got this issue. One user of few thousand. He's using Samsung Galaxy J7 (2016).

Answer (score 0):

It was happening for me as well. I couldn't reproduce it but after analyzing Crashlytics log history I realized it started happening after I moved to app bundle. **So I moved back to apk** and now I am not getting these issue anymore.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xx.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0700e7
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2733)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1480)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6146)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

[image]